# Sort data in React native from Firebase database

Tags: sorting, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I just found in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data this

> You can only use one order-by method at a time. Calling an order-by method multiple times in the same query throws an error.

But I have to sort data with two children: the first one can be equal to [0,1,2,3], list the items for each value separately and then report those values in alphabetic order.

```
        this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('path').orderByChild('ItemId').equalTo(0);

getRef() {
        return firebaseApp.database().ref();
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('path').orderByChild('ItemId').startAt(0).endAt(3);
```

and then do the alphabetic ordering of the result by yourself.